# Stop a user entering data if another cell in a table contains data

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I may be way off here but I've made a start on some code and it isn't working (it throws an error).

Essentially, I have a table (Table18) that has - for example - a column for Group 1 and a column for Group 2.  On any given row, if there is data in Group 1 (rng), I don't want the user to be able to enter data into Group 2 (rng2) and vice-versa.

It must be for the selected row only, however many there may be.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub CheckGroupIsPopulated()
' Description

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table18")
    'Table name
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
    'It should check if there is a value in the adjacent cell here
    Set rng2 = tbl.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange
    'The code should execute if a user selects a cell in this range

    If ActiveCell = rng2 Then
        If rng.Cells.Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Unable to enter data if text is containted in Defined Entry"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        Else
        End If
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure, but it seems like you want a [Selection Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange)

Answer (score 3):

You can use data validation for this, without using VBA at all.

Select the column that you want to be conditionally protected, go to Data --> Data Validation. And select "Custom" from the drop down.

You can now enter a formula to determine if the user will be allowed to enter data into your protected cell.
If the formula returns `TRUE`, the input will be allowed, otherwise it will throw up a warning or an error depending upon what you enter in the "Error Alert" tab of the Data Validation form.

In my example below, if a "Y" is entered into the first column, the user will not be able to enter anything into the other columns of that row, but you can adjust it to your liking.

[image]